# Point otbApplication for python to the relevant OTB DLL's

Tags: python, remote-sensing, windows, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

I installed the latest OTB and Monteverdi on a Win 7 machine. Via osgeo4w I downloaded otbApplication for python, without any dependencies.

Python, gdal, numpy scipy and so forth was custom build from source and using it with the osgeo python and related dependencies "break" the custom build python and modules.

I copied the three otbApplication files from the osgeo4w install location to the custom python install location (C:\Python27\Lib). When importing otbApplication, an Import error is raised stating

```
>>> import otbApplication

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import otbApplication
  File "C:\Program Files\Monteverdi-3.0\lib\orfeotoolbox\python\otbApplication.py", line 28, in <module>
    _otbApplication = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Monteverdi-3.0\lib\orfeotoolbox\python\otbApplication.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_otbApplication', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

My question is:
How do I go about pointing the otbApplication for python to the relevant OTB DLL's in a windows 7 environment?

Answer (score 1):

From release 5.4 OTB will distribute standalone binary packages which contain all exe and applications in a self contained archive for LINUX/Windows/Mac.

5.4 is not released yet (targeted for May) but you can already try it (nightly package are available on a daily basis).

32 bits system:

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/packages/nightly/latest/OTB-5.4.0-win32.zip

64 bits system:

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/packages/nightly/latest/OTB-5.4.0-win64.zip

Hope it helps.